# How to make 'tags' affect a relation(column_property)

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on a project with Flask-SQLAlchemy.

The model looks like this:
cars have components,
components can have issues

car has a column_property 'needs_repair' which is true when a car's component has issues

```
 needs_repair = column_property(exists().where(and_(
        carcomponent.columns['car_id'] == id,
        carcomponent.columns['component_id'] == componentissue.columns['component_id']
    )))
```

I added a table for tags with a 'skip'-column, tags are assigned via a table issue_car_tag(ignoring components, only referencing specific car-issue-relations).

Now, i want needs_repair to be true if all assigned tags have skip = False or no tags are assigned

How do I extend the column_property to achieve this?

edit:
Model/table definitions:

```
class Component(Base):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    [...]
    issues = db.relationship('ISsue', secondary=componentissue, lazy='dynamic',
        back_populates='components')

    cars = db.relationship('Car', lazy = 'dynamic', secondary=carcomponent,
        back_populates="component"

    broken = column_property(exists().where(componentissue.columns['component_id'] == id))

class Car(Base):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   [...] 
   components = db.relationship('Component', secondary=carcomponent,
        back_populates="cars", lazy='dynamic')
   needs_repair = column_property(exists().where(and_(
            carcomponent.columns['car_id'] == id,
            carcomponent.columns['component_id'] == componentissue.columns['component_id']
        )))

class Issue(Base):
    __tablename__ = "issues"
    [...]    
    components = db.relationship('Component' lazy = 'dynamic', secondary=componentissue,
        back_populates='issues')

class Tag(Base):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False, default="")
    skip = db.Column(db.Boolean, default = False)

class Issue_Car_Tag(Base):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'))
    car_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('car.id'))
    issue_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('issue.id'))
    tag = db.relationship('Tag', backref=db.backref('issue_car_tags'))
    car = db.relationship('Car',  backref=db.backref('issue_car_tags'))
    issue = db.relationship('Issue',  backref=db.backref('issue_car_tags'))
```

Comment: What should it be if there are no tags?

Comment: then it should be true, basically, tags with skip=True create an exception for needs_repair, so if all of a car's issues are tagged with a skip-tag, needs_repair should be false.

Comment: Do you mean if there exists issues, but no tags, then it should be true. It'd seem a bit odd that a car needs repair, if it has no issues. So can there be issues without tags? This might be self evident somehow, but I've missed it.

Comment: Yes, exactly, there can be issues without tags, but no tags without issues, as the tags are assigned by the Issue_Car_Tag-table

Comment: So one more question and I promise I'll try and shut up then: from all this I'd gather that `Issue_Car_Tag` may contain rows where `tag_id` is null, but `car_id` and `issue_id` point to their respective rows.

Comment: No :) in Issue_Car_Tag all 3 columns are filled when a tag is assigned, tags are added central and then selected, issues and cars are related via components table, but tags regard cars<->issues

Comment: One more thing: what DB?

Comment: flask-sqlalchemy is connected to a postgresql-db

Answer (score 1):

If you'd move the definition of Car after the definitions of Tag and Issue_Car_Tag or reference those tables in some other manner, you could produce the following query construction

```
func.coalesce(func.bool_and(not_(Tag.skip)), False).\
    select().\
    where(Tag.id == Issue_Car_Tag.tag_id).\
    where(Issue_Car_Tag.car_id == id).\
    as_scalar()
```

and use that in an OR with your existing check:

```
needs_repair = column_property(
    or_(func.coalesce(func.bool_and(not_(Tag.skip)), False).
            select().
            where(Tag.id == Issue_Car_Tag.tag_id).
            where(Issue_Car_Tag.car_id == id).
            as_scalar(),
        exists().where(and_(
            carcomponent.c.car_id == id,
            carcomponent.c.component_id == componentissue.c.component_id))))
```

The query selects tags related to a car using the association table issue_car_tag and [aggregates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) the skip values, [coalescing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html) an empty result or all null values.

Note that this results in false if no tags are assigned, so you have to handle that separately. If I've understood your existing query correctly, this is handled by your EXISTS expression already. Put another way, the new query results in true if tags exist and all have skip set to false.